# RelativeLayout textviews overlapping

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a rather simple ListView row:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tournament_name"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:textSize="25dp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tournament_winner"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:textSize="25dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

When the text of `"@+id/tournament_name"`is long - it overlaps with the one from `"@+id/tournament_winner"` and I don't understand why.

I tried using `android:singleLine="false"`to no avail. I also tried using `android:inputType="textMultiLine"`as the docu says `android:singleLine="false"` is deprecated but then I get the warning: `Attribute android:inputType should not be used with <TextView>: Change element type to 
 <EditText> ?` so no good here as well.

I also tried using `android:ellipsize="end"` but this doesn't work. I assume it is because the text in the left `TextView ("@+id/tournament_name")` is NOT long enough to fill up the full width of the `ListView` (which code is not sowing here).

I was sure that if I use `android:layout_width="wrap_content"`the two TextView fields shouldn't overlap.

Here is an example (see the second line):

[image]

Any further ideas how this could be fixed?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

```
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/tournament_winner" in First TextView.
```

Also set `android:maxLines="1"` and `Fix width for tournament winner` because when it gets long tournament name cant see...

**row.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tournament_name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/tournament_winner"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:text="NAMEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEE"
        android:textSize="25dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tournament_winner"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:text="WINER"
        android:textSize="25dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Wouldn't this result in an error at compile time? tournament_winner doesn't exist yet, so how can anything be aligned to it?

Comment: This is addressed in the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11594737/369480  You need to ensure you specify a + in the ID.

Comment: Kudos to ndroid:layout_toLeftOf="@id/tournament_winner". it works

Answer (score 11):

Thank you very much for your answer - sorry it took me some time to respond. I ended up using your `android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/tournament_winner"` but left the single line and the margin to the left unused, as the result seemed perfect to me (hope this is also the case for other devices).

One thing though - in the first text view (tournament_name) I had to use `android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/tournament_winner"`and not `android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/tournament_winner"` - pay attention to the added **+**. For some reason I get an error using `android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/tournament_winner"`: *Error: No resource found that matches the given name...* so it seems that it is possible and NEEDED to define the resource in the time of calling it because the system doesn't know it before it was defined.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tournament_name"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/tournament_winner"            
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"        
    android:textSize="25dp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tournament_winner"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"         
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:textSize="25dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Just change the order of adding TextViews in your xml if you don't want to add the +. So first add tournament_winner and then tournament_name.

Comment: I don't think you need ```android:id="@+id/tournament_winner"```, just use ```android:id="@id/tournament_winner"``` since ```tournament_winner``` has already been defined in ```layout_toLeftOf```

Answer (score -4):

You can use single text view in place of two and simply display both strings in one text view !!